# Replacing "۔ "with <s> in python

Tags: python, nlp, urdu

I am working in python2.7 with urdu text. what i am doing is reading a text file and replacing "۔" with "end of senetence marker" it is replacing in file but it is placing this in start. i want to add markers at the place of "-" that is at the end of sentences. My code is here:

```
import codecs
import re
import sys
import io

fil = codecs.open("aa.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
fil1 = codecs.open("a.txt","w",encoding="utf-8")
for line in fil:
    for ch in line:
        ch = ch.replace(u'۔','</s><s>')
        fil1.write(ch)
```

my original data is:

> میرا نام احمد ہے۔ میں پڑھتا ہو۔

my file after trying to replace is:

[image]

kindly help me or suggest me what can i do.

Comment: I think what's happening here is an interaction between LTR and RTL. Looking at selection behavior, everything is in the correct order, but it renders, I _think_, as if each sentence is an RTL fragment embedded in LTR text. By selecting characters in the answer below, I see that the characters are, in order: the first sentence, the replacement text, the second sentence, the replacement text, but this is laid out LTR for me, and matches your screenshot.

Comment: @nwchase so how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
```

> Function parameters
>
> 1. s: The string to search and replace from.
> 2. old: The old sub-string you wish to replace.
> 3. new: The new sub-string you wish to put in-place of the old one.
> 4. maxreplace: The maximum number of times you wish to replace the
>      sub-string.

And your function:

```
ch = ch.replace(u'۔','</s><s>')
```

Where is the **string** you whant to make change as a parameter? I did not understand what is **u** for there
Try this:

```
ch = ch.replace(ch,'۔','</s><s>')
```

> And maybe the program reads from right to left but writes from left to
>   right.

Comment: u is for unicode. and i have replaced other characters by simply using this function they worked but not this one